# Cognito registration with Facebook does not create user

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-login, amazon-cognito

I get token from Facebook pass it to Cognito but it does not create a user in the user pool. What should I do additionally to create a user?

```
FacebookProvider *socialProvider = [[FacebookProvider alloc] init];
                    [socialProvider initWithTokens:@{@"graph.facebook.com":result.token.tokenString}];

                    AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *socialCredentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                                                                initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                                identityPoolId:CognitoIdentityUserPoolId
                                                                                identityProviderManager:socialProvider];
                    // Self.socialProvider is that class that implements AWSIdentityProviderManager protocol

                    AWSServiceConfiguration *fbConfiguration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc]
                                                                initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:socialCredentialsProvider];
                    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = fbConfiguration;

                    //create a pool
                    AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration alloc] initWithClientId:CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientId  clientSecret:CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientSecret poolId:CognitoIdentityUserPoolId];

                    [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool registerCognitoIdentityUserPoolWithConfiguration:fbConfiguration userPoolConfiguration:configuration forKey:@"UserPool"];

                    AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool *pool = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool CognitoIdentityUserPoolForKey:@"UserPool"];

                    pool.delegate = self;

                    NSLog(@"socialCredentialsProvider.getIdentityId: %@", socialCredentialsProvider.getIdentityId);
```

Answer (score 1):

The iOS API call that you are using is an Identity Pool API call, and not a User Pool API call. Cognito Identity Pools and Cognito User Pools are highly decoupled in nature, and any linked login/Identity ID is not reflected in the User Pool. Cognito User Pools are used for authentication, and Cognito Identity Pools are used for authentication. In context of network security, authentication means verifying an identity, and authorization involves giving access to a set of resources(In this case, AWS Resources via temporary credentials vended by AWS STS).

If you would like to use Facebook Federated Logins in your iOS Application, I would recommend you to read about the OAuth 2.0 Compliant [AUTHORIZATION Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html). 
An example AUTHORIZATION Endpoint URL with the Identity Provider being Facebook follows the given format:

https://(COGNITO_USER_POOL_DOMAIN_NAME)/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=https://www.google.com&response_type=token&client_id=XXXX&identity_provider=Facebook

I would recommend you to read through the [difference](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/cognito-user-pool-vs-identity-pool.html) between Cognito User Pools and Cognito Identity Pools to further understand how the Cognito service works.

Comment: thank you! Can you please help how to pass the facebook token using this url ? I tried to check but get an error of invalid url format

Comment: and can I use this url from code and will I get Cognito token in the response ?

Comment: and I get such error in responce: error=redirect_mismatch&client_id=5q4oo7ho6fs1ug6h9k43t0jgtu } { Status Code: 400, Headers {

Comment: lightyagami,  can't understant what should be as redirect_uri using this in ios app?

Comment: so just tried to do smth with oauth2 but cant understand. I loged in into facebook and get Facebook token, and how can I exchange this token to sign up to cognito and get cognito user and tokens?

Comment: "I loged in into facebook and get Facebook token"
Did you hit the AUTHORIZATION Endpoint for your Cognito User Pool with Facebook as the IdP?

Comment: yes and I get response with the url and if I invoke this url from web browser it creates the user in cognito  but how can I use it in code?

Comment: and I suppose I should send my FB token to the AUTHORIZATION Endpoint ? But how could I do it?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the Cognito User Pool Federated Identities AuthFlow. 

The AUTHORIZATION Endpoint uses the hosted UI Auth Flow, and there's a handshaking process between Cognito and Facebook(as a social provider IdP) that generates a JWT ID Token and an Access Token.

Comment: oww,, it's so bad, but can I use it somehow without any hosted UI. I get FB token by myself and then I need to pass this token to cognito and register a user. Could you help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by obtaining the "Facebook" Token? Are you referring to the JWT Tokens obtained after using Cognito's AUTHORIZATION Endpoint with Facebook mentioned as the Identity Provider? Also, why would you require a JWT Token to register users? Kindly elucidate. You might not be lucid on how Authentication and Authorization works in context of Network security and Amazon Cognito. I'll implore you to thoroughly read through Cognito's official [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/index.html#lang/en_us) before asking a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Really appreciate 
There is a lot of things I can't make work with Cognito and facebook registration. And I can't find any working example..
Maybe you have some working sample of registration to cognito on Obj-C or SWIFT, it would be a real help (using your approach with endpoints or any other option)?

Comment: - I've tried their AWSMobileClient, and the Facebook did not work there as weel.
- Also, I've tried the usual API (The code I've posted in this question), and it did not register user
- And your way with auth2..

If you can help with any sample project for any case? I am struggling with this Cognito Facebook already a week.. thanks

Comment: Actually I've managed to register with basic cognito registration, and can't do it with Facebook (

Comment: JWT tokens we need to pass to our own server after registration of a user, cause we will have our own id managment system on top of a cognito